# Whats a tag based file organizer?

Tags: file-management, archiving, tags

I'm finishing professional school and over the years have acquired a pile of notes and articles that I'd like to hang onto.  I'd like to add to them and create sort of an archive of article and files that may be useful down the road.  I'd also like to organize this collection of files not only by simple grouping but also with tags.  I feel like that will make searching through them years later much easier.  Suggestions on software that would be good for this?  Just a general file manager, something that uses tags that can be attached to each file?

Comment: Related/Dupe: [Where to find a tag based file manager?](http://superuser.com/questions/78473/where-to-find-a-tag-based-file-manager?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

[Leap](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/leap/index.html) is a general-purpose file manager that uses OS X's integrated Spotlight search for tagging, filtering, etc.

---

[Yep](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/yep/index.html) by the same company is a more specialized document manager.

[Together](http://reinventedsoftware.com/together/) is also more specialized and capable of managing a database of documents, as is [EagleFiler](http://c-command.com/eaglefiler/).

Answer (score 2):

Try out Tabbles
http://www.tabbles.net

> Tabbles allows you to organize your
>   files and documents independently from
>   the folder structure. Or to refine
>   your existing folder organization.

Answer (score 1):

The best note-keeping application I've ever used is [KeyNote](http://code.google.com/p/keynote-nf/) (now called KeyNote NF). It keeps notes in an organized tree based structure. You can hyperlink to web addresses or other notes, encrypt notes, highlight portions for emphasis, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions, perhaps one of these two may work well for you:

Tagnotes (alpha stage as of 2011-Mar-02)
  http://tagnotes.sourceforge.net/

My Notes Keeper
  http://www.mynoteskeeper.com/

Answer (score 1):

Evernote. http://evernote.com/evernote/

"Evernote makes it easy to remember things big and small from your everyday life using your computer, phone, tablet and the web."