# tools to manage your documents, songs, images with many categories?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management

**Problem:**

I have collection of many images or books which can belong to multiple categories like

```
C, algorithms, interview, database, OS, windows,
```

for images

```
icons, website headers, awesome, minimal, abstract, print design, photography
```

For songs

```
new songs, old songs, romantic songs, comedy songs, awesome songs, slow songs, fast songs
```

**To properly organize all the items I have to create folder for each category and place duplicate copies or shortcuts (making shortcuts is also a hassle) in each folder. I want a alternate solution to this method**

Current file browsers seem to ignore these type of cases or such functionality is hidden to normal user. (I am doubtful about the folder technology implementation in file browsers there should be something like tagging).

Does there exist a software or script or good folder structure to decrease my effort ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [tag based file organizer](http://superuser.com/questions/252537/tag-based-file-organizer), also see [Where to find a tag based file manager?](http://superuser.com/questions/78473/where-to-find-a-tag-based-file-manager?rq=1)

Comment: You said Windows-7 but I remember there is something in the likes of tags hidden among there. OSX has tagging since Leopard, but never used it full-scale. Is there something blocking you from just putting your files in your folders instead of shortcutting?

Comment: I know they have tags but it is not easy to use them, to tag each file with a tag there is no easy process. second point you mentioned is just waste of space. I am just saying we are adjusting to current design of file managers it can be improved